# Selenium how to loop through all classes in div and click on each one?

Tags: python, selenium

Hi guys im trying to make a script that will loop through all projects on rarirty tools and click on the divs one by one and then get me the projects details. However for some reason my script is not doing anything.... im not getting any errors either , just its not clicking on the divs for some reason. All the divs have a classname of w-72 as you can see below

```
<div class="flex flex-row flex-wrap justify-center">
<div class="mb-4 ml-4 overflow-hidden border border-gray-300 rounded-lg shadow-md bgCard dark:border-gray-800">
<div class="w-72">
<a href="/garagexyz-genesis" class="">
<div class="relative w-full overflow-hidden" style="height: 220px;">
<!----> 
<img src="https://projects.b-cdn.net/garagexyz-genesis/header.jpg?height=220" class="object-cover object-center w-full h-full"> 
 <div class="flex flex-row mt-2"><div class="p-2 ml-2">
<div class="font-bold text-pink-600 dark:text-gray-300">
            GarageXYZ Genesis 500
          </div>
```

Here is the code

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    
   
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\chromedriver.exe")
    driver.maximize_window()
    index=0
    driver.get("https://rarity.tools/")
  
    while True:
       divs = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'w-72')
       print(divs)
       try: 
           divs[index].click()
       except IndexError:
           break  # no more elements, exit the loop
    
       # get project info
       # ...
    
       driver.back()
    
       index += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply loop over the found elements and then extract the link by accessing the child `a` tag and getting its `href` attribute.

In order to avoid stale elements you can story the links in a list and open them separately

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://rarity.tools/")

links = [e.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//a").get_attribute("href") for e in driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'w-72')]

for l in links:
    driver.get(l)
```